# Rosser's trick practice exam question

Tags: computability, solution-verification, incompleteness

A practice exam in recursion theory has the following question about Rosser's trick (I guess this is the correct name):

[image: Practice exam question]

I use the following notion of representability:

[image: Definition of representability]

The only theorem I need concerning this definition is that all total computable ($\mu$-recursive) functions are representable. I use this without further mention.

My answer goes as follows:

**(a)** Let us first analyze what the $T$-sentence $\chi(\bar{m})$ represents, it says: "for all $n_1$ that code a $T$-proof for the sentence $\chi(\bar{m})$ there exists $n_0 < n_1$ coding a $T$-proof of $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$".

If $T \vdash \chi(\bar{m})$ then there is some $n_1$ that codes a $T$-proof for $\chi(\bar{m})$, and $T$ knows about this by representability. Hence $T$ proves that there exists $n_0 < \bar{n_1}$ such that it codes a $T$-proof of $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$. However, $T$ also shows that none of $\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \dots, \overline{n_1-1}$ codes a $T$-proof for $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$: otherwise by representability $T \vdash \neg\chi(\bar{m})$ would be coded by some $n$, so that in particular $T \vdash \neg\chi(\bar{m})$, which cannot be since $T$ is consistent.

So $T$ proves that there exists $n_0 < \bar{n_1}$ such that it codes a $T$-proof of $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$ but that it cannot be any one of $\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \dots, \overline{n_1-1}$, contradicting one of the axiom schemes that $Ar_0$ satisfies. Hence $T \supset Ar_0$ is inconsistent if $T \vdash \chi(\bar{m})$, so that $T \nvdash \chi(\bar{m})$ must hold if $T$ is consistent.

**(b)** Suppose that $T \vdash \neg\chi(\bar{m})$, then $T$ proves that there exists a number $n_1$ that codes a $T$-proof for $\chi(\bar{m})$ such that there is no code $< \! n_1$ for a $T$-proof of $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$. Let $n_0$ code $T \vdash \neg\chi(\bar{m})$, then by representability $T$ proves this as well, and therefore $T$ also proves that there is some $T$-proof of $\chi(\bar{m})$ with code number $n_1 \leq \bar{n_0}$.
Now we can do the same thing as for (a), but with the roles of $\chi(\bar{m})$ and $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$ reversed, to conclude $T \nvdash \neg\chi(\bar{m})$.

I'm in doubt whether my reasoning here is sound. I'm especially concerned since I didn't use the hint in part (b). Usually this is a bad omen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems to be assuming that the formula $\chi$ represents the predicate $\tilde \chi$ it expresses. That would be true, as you allude to, if it were a recursive predicate, but it is not (minor note: you talk of functions, whereas this is a predicate / unary relation). Just because a formula is built out of recursive formulas doesn't mean it is recursive, at least not when there are quantifiers involved.

And it really can't represent the predicate, provided that the conclusion of the theorem is correct. If $\chi$ represents $\tilde \chi$ then $T$ proves each true instance and refutes each false instance. Thus there are no undecidable instances.

**Edit**
Okay, I'll give a solution. I'll try not to be too detailed so you have at least a couple small gaps to fill in.

Two of the key facts we need you already mentioned. The first is that if $\varphi(\vec x)$ expresses some recursive arithmetical relation then $\varphi$ represents that relation in $T.$ The second is that if $T$ is consistent and $\varphi(x_1,\ldots x_m)$ represents an $m$-ary relation in $T,$ then for any $n_1,\ldots n_m\in\mathbb N,$ $\varphi(n_1,\ldots n_m)$ is true if and only if $T\vdash \varphi(\bar n_1,\ldots \bar n_m).$ The final thing we need is the fact that if a relation is recursive, so is any bounded quantification of it, and so while an unbounded quantification of $\psi$ or $\bar \psi$ might not be representable just cause $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ are, bounded quantifications are.

You are correct in your interpretation of what $\chi(\bar m)$ means and it's good to keep in mind: it means that if there is a proof in $T$ of $\chi(\bar m)$ then there is a proof of $\lnot \chi(\bar m)$ with a smaller code number.

For (a) assume $T\vdash \chi(\bar m).$ Let $n$ be the code number of some proof of this. Then, instantiating the universal quantifier in $\chi(\bar m),$ we get a proof in $T$ that if $\bar n$ codes a proof of $\chi(\bar m),$ then there is a proof of $\lnot\chi(\bar m)$ with shorter code than $\bar n.$ But by representability, $T$ proves that $\bar n$ codes a proof of $\chi(\bar m),$ and so $T$ proves there is a proof of $\lnot\chi(\bar m)$ with shorter code than $\bar n.$ Since this is a bounded quantification of something recursive, it is recursive and thus representable, so the fact that $T$ proves it (and is consistent) means it is true and so $T\vdash \lnot\chi(\bar m),$ which contradicts its consistency.

For (b), assume $T\vdash\lnot\chi(\bar m)$ and let $n$ be the code number of the proof. $T\vdash\lnot\chi(\bar m)$ means $$T\vdash\exists x_2(\psi(\bar m, x_2)\land \lnot\exists x_0 < x_2\bar\psi(\bar m,x_0)).$$ Working in $T,$ instantiate $x_2,$ assume $x_2 \ge \bar n,$ and observe this is impossible since $\bar \psi(\bar m,\bar n)$ (which is provable in $T$ by representability). Thus $$T\vdash\exists x_2<\bar n(\psi(\bar m, x_2)\land \lnot\exists x_0 < x_2\bar\psi(\bar m,x_0)).$$ Now this is a bounded quantification, so by representability (and consistency of $T$) it is true, and so $T\vdash\chi(\bar m),$ contradicting the consistency of $T.$

Comment: Good, this is what I more or less came up with as well, except that I avoided talking about representability of sentences since the definition talks about functions/relations (but I'm sure that should be fine as well). However, I'm not quite sure how this uses the hint. Could you point that out? Thanks for helping me out so far!

Comment: Actually, thinking about the hint, I didn't do part (b) quite the way they intended (though I don't think it's wrong). What they were going for was to do a direct proof of $\chi(\bar m)$ in $T$ as follows: let $x_2$ be arbitrary and assume $\psi(\bar m, x_2)$ holds. Since $T\vdash \lnot\chi(\bar m)$ and $T$ is consistent, for any $k$, we can prove $\lnot\psi(\bar m, \bar k),$ so we can prove $x_2>\bar n$ (where $n$ is the code of the proof for $\chi(\bar m)$) and so since we can prove $\bar\psi(\bar m, \bar n)$ we have $\exists x_0<x_2\bar\psi(\bar m)$ and hence we have proven $\chi(\bar m).$

Comment: Also, i think the reasoning I gave for (a) can be turned into a direct proof in $T$ for $\lnot\chi(\bar m)$ too, and it comes out a little simpler. It's clear you can prove $\chi(\bar m, \bar n)$ and not a difficult argument to show you can prove $\forall x_0<\bar n\lnot\bar\psi(\bar m,x_0)$, then just take their conjunction and existentially generalize on $\bar n$ and you have a proof of $\lnot\chi(\bar m).$

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect our discussion (and in the same vein suggested an edit to your answer). I emailed my professor about this, he said: "You assume incorrectly that object $x_2$ of which $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$ says it exists is a number. In an arbitrary model of $T$ this can perfectly well be non-standard, with many predecessors about which the representation theory says nothing. The hint implies to look for a concrete proof of $\neg\chi(\bar{m})$". (My translation)

Comment: I don't understand what he means by this. What I did is the same as what you did, correct (see updated question)? Why would it be wrong? What does it have to do with models of $T$ and non-standard elements? I guess your second solution is what the hint suggests you do. I'm confused. Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: So I talked to the teacher again, and this is indeed the intended solution. But I'd still like to know what is wrong with our original approach (if anything). If you can address that in your answer as well, I'll accept it and add a small bounty as token of appreciation for your time.

Comment: @Jori the intended solution is the one I put in the comment started “Actually, thinking about the hint...”? I don’t think there’s anything wrong with my other version... we can assume it is standard because we can prove it’s less than $n$... but will cross check with your professor’s comment and what you wrote.

Comment: @Jori of what you wrote in (b) is what you sent, then I think I can see why your professor might have dismissed the argument, since you seem to imply $n_1$ is a (standard) number whereas it doesn’t have to be, a priori. But we can show it is since we know nothing less than it can be a code of a proof of $\lnot \chi(\bar m)$, and so $n_0$ is greater than or equal to it and hence $n_1$ is standard.

Comment: I don't know what "standard" means. I know I say "number" but that is just for my own intuition. I would be just as happy saying "object". So I am missing something more fundamental here.

Comment: @Jori you can read up on nonstandard models of arithmetic. The takeaway here is we need to be careful when arguing “semantically” (which is why I said “working in $T$” a bunch and made sure everything I said after that could actually be proved in $T$). For instance, it can happen that $T\vdash \exists x\phi(x)$ and yet for every $n\in \mathbb N$, $T\vdash\lnot \phi(\bar n).$ This is called $\omega$-inconsistency, and actually Rosser’s trick is necessary only for the special case where $T$ is consistent but $\omega$-inconsistent... the rest can be handled with Godel’s more simple sentence.

Comment: I would tell your professor that $x_2$ can be proved to be less than $\bar n_0$ in $T$ and see what they say.

Comment: Okay, that's what I figured, but your comment clarified it. I can imagine many beginners make mistakes where they unjustly reason semantically without consideration of non-standard models (and make implicit appeal to completeness of FOL). But in my mind what I wrote and what you wrote is apart from your last sentence completely identical, except that I talked about $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ in terms of what they represent (but that doesn't matter, right?). I cannot see where I used that $n_1$ is a standard number (except that I might have phrased myself more clearly).

Comment: (Cont.) I even show that $T \vdash n_1 \leq \bar{n_0}$, from which it follows that $n_1$ is standard anyway, right?

Comment: @Jori Yes, I agree.

Comment: Okay, good. So I should just remove "number" and replace it by "object"? I have accepted your answer! I will look how I can reward some additional points, but I'm not sure how that works without starting a bounty. Unrelated: may I ask what your background is in?

Comment: I guess just make it a little clearer that you can prove in $T$ that the $x_2$ that exists is less than a given code of a proof of $\chi(\bar m)$, and that’s how we know an actual natural number coding the proof actually exists (hypothetically in this proof by contradiction of course). I would avoid arguing semantically unless you’re very explicit about what is going on (e.g. “let $M$ be an arbitrary model of $T$ and let $x_2\in M$ be such that...”).

Comment: The only way is a bounty but there’s no need. I have a background in physics and math and work in the private sector. No formal training in logic per se but I’ve done a lot of reading recently (and have some badges on MSE :) ).